# Create a minimum centered on zero operator

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a central tendency operator (like the mean or the median) which would follow this logic:

**For a given array, return the value closest to zero if all values have the same sign and zero otherwise**

In other words:

- if all values > 0 return min(array)
- if all values < 0 return max(array)
- else return 0

Here is the most optimized implementation I managed to do:

```
def zero_min(x):
    if len(x) == 1:
        return x[0]
    else:
        tmin = np.min(x)
        tmax = np.max(x)
        return (tmin if tmin == abs(tmin) else tmax) if tmin*tmax > 0 else 0
```

The issue is that I want it to be very efficient in order to use it in a rolling window (using pandas.Series.rolling) on 8.5M values of type float64, like this:

`df = df.rolling(timedelta(seconds=5)).apply(zero_min, raw=True)`

But this function is painfully slow to execute: for a window of 5s it takes 33.34s, while pandas.Series.rolling.mean takes 0.15s and pandas.Series.rolling.median 1.01 (and the median should be longer to compute, as it is an operation more complex).

Would you know how to optimize it so that it is at least as fast as the median?
I guess I would have to use matrix calculation or code the operation in C but I don't know how to do that.

You can reproduce the data to process using

```
import random
n = 8467200
df = pd.Series([random.random() for i in range(n)], index=pd.date_range(datetime.now(), datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=n-1), freq='1S'))
```

Comment: `df.rolling('5s').apply(zero_min, raw=True, engine='numba')`? Please provide a [mre] to benchmark alternative approaches.

Comment: Minimal reproducible example added. Using numba indeed greatly improves performances, I recorded an execution duration of 1.2s

Answer (score 1):

avoid using `apply`, you can do something like this:

```
min_val = df['some_col'].rolling(timedelta(seconds=5), min_periods=1).min()
max_val = df['some_col'].rolling(timedelta(seconds=5), min_periods=1).max()

# perform the logics on these series
df['new_col'] = np.select((min_val.gt(0) | min_val.eq(max_val), max_val < 0), 
                          (min_val, max_val), 0)
```

Comment: It is the fastest solution I tried, I just added the convertion back to a Series `df = pd.Series(np.select((min_val.gt(0) | min_val.eq(max_val), max_val < 0), (min_val, max_val), 0), index=df.index)`. Thanks!